# Double checking that this is standard for all tenancies: Document Type and Relates To

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, metadata, sitepages

[image: Screen shot]

This is metadata of the Site Pages library (M365, Modern). How those columns are supposed to be used?

Comment: I don't have this metadata/fields associated with site pages in our tenant. Did you enable any feature or added this columns manually or using custom content type?

Comment: ok i found out it was added by my company, should I delete the topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Document Type` and `Relates To` columns are not standard columns across all SharePoint online tenants - not provided by Microsoft by default.

As per my comments above, those must be added to site pages library by enabling any feature on your SharePoint site or someone from your company added this columns manually to site pages library or using custom content type in the library.